# Import forms in template tags

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm stuck with a little problem, at the moment i'm developing template tags for an app, and I have to import a form, `.forms import MyModelForm` doesn't work because is not in the same directory ...

I did a trick for the model with the `get_model('app', 'Model')`, but I didn't find anything like that for forms.

My structure is really classic :

```
app
|-templates
|-templatestags
| |-__init__
| |-app_tags.py
|-forms.py
|-models.py
|-views.py
```

I want to keep my app independent from the project.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
from ..forms import MyModelForm
```

For more info on imports, please read [PEP 328](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/).

Comment: I got this error :
'app' is not a valid tag library: ImportError raised loading myproject.app.templatetags.app: No module named forms